# updating a field using right & charindex functions

Tags: sql, t-sql, charindex

I have data in myfield that looks like:

```
UNDC, UNKN
UNDC, MUA
UNKN, BUS
```

I want to update the myfield leaving only text after the comma.

I've been using a combination of right & charindex, but when I run the update statement everything is being erased. This is what I have now:

```
update mytable
set myfield = RIGHT(myfield, charindex(',', myfield)-1)
where myfield like 'un%' and myfield like '%,%'
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

`RIGHT()` is counting characters from the end of the string.  That has nothing to do with what `CHARINDEX()` returns, because that function returns a position counting from the beginning.

You can do what you want using `substring()`:

```
update mytable
    set myfield = substring(myfield, charindex(',', myfield) + 1, length(myfield))
    where myfield like 'un%,%' ;
```

Notice that I combined the two conditions in the `where` clause into a single condition.

Comment: 1^ vote for combining both conditions in the where clause! that's awesome!